# Building and Running on a device from Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

To run my application on a device I think I have to ensure that the app. is debuggable by setting the android:debuggable attribute of the `<application>` element to true in the **build.gradle** file, (as it says in the doc. http://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-studio.html) but this is how my file looks like:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are targeting wrong `build.gradle` (top level). You need to do it in lower level `build.gradle` in `android` block:

```
android {

    //...

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            debuggable true
        }
        customDebuggableBuildType {
            debuggable true
        }
        release {
            debuggable false
        }
    }

   //...

}
```

---

Also it can be done in old way by adding `android:debuggable="true"` to `AndroidManifest.xml` file in `<application` section.

Answer (score 1):

the android:debuggable attribute should be in your AndroidManifest.xml
Eg:

```
<application 
             android:debuggable="true">
 . . .
</application>
```